# Elasticsearch Facets Count returns different results

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have an interesting issue, when I run this request for **WA state**

```
{   
"query":{"bool":{"must":[ {"query_string":{"default_field":"State","query":"\"**wa**\""}}],"must_not":
            [],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":10,"sort":[],
        "facets":{ "States" : { "terms" : { "field" : "State" } } }
}
```

**Result**

> "facets": {
>           "States": {
>               "_type": "terms",
>               "missing": 0,
>               "total": 78201,
>               "other": 0,
>               "terms": [
>                   {
>                       **"term": "wa",
>                       "count": 78201**
>                   }
>               ]
>           }

But if I run this request for **all states**

```
{   
"query":{ "bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1,"sort":[],
      "facets":{ "States" : { "terms" : { "field" : "State" } } }
}
```

Return less count for WA, I expected to have the same number than the query before

> "facets": {
>           "States": {
>               "_type": "terms",
>               "missing": 209814,
>               "total": 2549592,
>               "other": 1200206,
>               "terms": [
>                   {
>                       "term": "ca",
>                       "count": 305780
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "mi",
>                       "count": 185574
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "fl",
>                       "count": 160341
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "tn",
>                       "count": 135670
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "il",
>                       "count": 132751
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "tx",
>                       "count": 113359
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "oh",
>                       "count": 98598
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "pa",
>                       "count": 84601
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "term": "co",
>                       "count": 79796
>                   },
>                   **{
>                       "term": "wa",
>                       "count": 52916
>                   }**
>               ]
>           }
>       } }

So, how elasticsearch facets really work?

Thanks as always

Comment: Please edit and format your question properly

Comment: Anyone has a thought?